# Why can't we have a Quick Sort with a complexity of O(1), even if we have a list of 1 item?

Tags: quicksort

While it would be really silly to do this, it I feel like it definitely can be done given the right algorithm. That said, why wouldn't the best case scenario for a quick sort be O(1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any implementation of QuickSort has to be defined for size-1 and even size-0 lists, because as you recursively divide the collection into smaller parts, you'll inevitably run into subsets of those sizes. Run it on paper and you'll see.

> why wouldn't the best case scenario for a quick sort be O(1)?

This is a misunderstanding of big-O notation. It describes how the algorithm scales as a function of the number of elements. QuickSort can never be O(1) because it minimally has to run through its recursive division strategy once, which takes (N*(log N)) iterations (hence scaling at O(N*(log N)) in the best case).

Comment: But if you have 1 element, you really can't "divide" that element into a subset... The pivot would be the same as the comparison no?

Comment: Yes, so when you implement the algorithm, you special-case those so they just return the 1 or 0-element subset immediately. You can think of QuickSort as a recursive function defined by parts, where QuickSort of a list of 0 or 1 element is the list itself, and QuickSort of a larger list is QuickSort applied to two subsets of the list, defined by the pivot partitioning strategy. It is still O(N * log(N)).

Comment: Would you mind providing a visual. Your explanation is hard to conceptualize. I'm new to this. And no, this is not a HW assignment! :)

Comment: I think you need to take a sheet of paper and a pencil and run it by yourself once ;) But regardless of the details, it's not O(1) because even if it runs in constant time for a list of 1 element, it does not *scale* in constant time as the number of elements grow, and that's what the O-notation describes.

Comment: @dlamblin that was pretty awesome!

Answer (score 0):

While you could start your implementation with a check for the size of the input and short-circuit for this case, the description of quicksort that I have would still perform a number of steps.

I read the first step as computing an index which partitions the subarray into two partitions either or both of which could be empty. Then recursively sort those subarrays with quicksort (given that they're empty this is where you end the recursion). The subarray is now sorted. It's said to be worst case *Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)* and average case *O(n lg n)*. If you substitute 1 in for *n* yes it looks kind of constant, but *O* is a bounds and isn't used this way.

That said, the implementations I've see would only partition if the input for the low index of the subarray is less than the input for the high index. IE a minimum of 2 elements in the subarray.